# Dynamically add attribute to script tag

Tags: javascript, c#

I need to add nonce attribute to the existing script tags from code behind C#.
Is there any way to add, tried the below code

```
 HtmlGenericControl attr = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
 attr.Attributes.Add("nonce", "<%= cspnonce %>");
 Page.Header.Controls.Add(attr);
```

but getting exception,

> The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control
> contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Share If any ways to implement,
Thanks in advance